# Is it possible to write to a remote file via FTP in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ftp

My application (which I'm trying to speed up) currently creates a local temp file and FTP uploads it to an ftp site.  Is there functionality to allow me to open a remote file on the FTP and write to it directly?  I believe android supports this.

Also if somebody could point me to a library/sample code that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL()` (see ["CFFTPStream Reference"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFFTPStreamRef/Reference/reference.html)) can be used to write data to a remote FTP file.

Apple provides the [SimpleFTPSample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt.html) sample project which demonstrates how to use `CFFTPStream`.